# Read http request body from REST client

Tags: rest, http, httprequest, wireshark, postman

How can i read the body of a POST request sent via REST client (something like [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm))? I think that it can be done also via wireshark, but honestly i don't know if there is some specific filter for this.

Thanks all

Comment: Just the raw HTTP request? Try fiddler.

Comment: i need to read the body of the request, can you please explain me how to do this with fiddler? Maybe put this as reply so i can mark it :)

Comment: Install [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and then you can see all requests.

Comment: Im using mac and the fiddler client seems very unstable and continue to crash before i can start any check

Comment: You can also use the browser dev tools. F12 on chrome and then look at the Network tab.  This will still capture the a postman request.